# Root test application question (usefulness of root test for the series $\sum 1/n^n$)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, multivariable-calculus

Is there a simple way to conclude whether the following series converges or diverges using the ratio test?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty   \frac{1}{n^n}
$$
My level is multi-variable calculus.
(**Note**: I know this can be easily found with the root or comparison tests)

Comment: I doubt that there is something easier than a comparison-test (where at least two essentially different functions do the job).

Comment: what do you mean by simple way using ratio test ? you can conclude that it's convergent by ratio test and $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} $ ${\to} 0$ as $n {\to}\infty$

Answer (score 6):

Ratio test does work: Let $a_n=1/n^n$ and it follows
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n^n}{(n+1)^{n+1}}\leq\frac{n^{n+1}}{(n+1)^{n+1}}=\left(1-\frac1{n+1}\right)^{n+1}\to\frac1e\quad\text{as }n\to\infty.$$
The ratio has limit $1/e<1$, so $\sum_na_n$ is convergent.